# Use default serialization for enums in a custom serializer

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I want to serialize a class `Foo` with a list of enum values called `Bar` using Jackson 2.9.6.

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonProperty("myBars")
    List<Bar> bars;
}
```

and

```
public enum Bar {
    @JsonProperty("Jane")
    JOHN,

    @JsonProperty("Roe")
    DOE
}
```

By default, the serialization outputs

```
{
    "myBars": ["Jane", "Roe"]
}
```

However, I want the serialization to output

```
{
    "myBars": "Jane;Roe"
}
```

So I added a custom serializer for the field `bars` that serializes as follows:

```
public void serialize(List<Object> list, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    gen.writeObject(StringUtils.join(list, ";")); // StringUtils from Apache Commons
}
```

Unsurprisingly, that results in

```
{
    "myBars": "JOHN;DOE"
}
```

**Question:** How can I use my custom serializer while keeping the default serialization for the enum values?

My solution so far is to iterate the list and use a separate `ObjectMapper` to serialize the single enum values. There are still some issues with escaped strings, but at least this seems to work. However, I wonder if this could be also done in a neat way.